# Discard changes and reset all data ionic/angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I would like to restore all the data that contains the variable `this.userConfiguration`, this variable is pushed with navparams from another page. I have tried with a copy but when I change another time the data is no longer reset because obviously, the copy takes the entered value.

**HTML File**: (the data is connected with the `this.userConfiguration variable`.)

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>

    <button ion-item (click)="changeValue()">
      <ion-label text-left>Valuta</ion-label>
      <ion-label text-right>{{userConfiguration.DEFAULTCURRENCY.ValueOfString}}</ion-label>
     </button>

     <button ion-item (click)="changeCountryRegion()">
       <ion-label text-left>Nation/Country</ion-label>
       <ion-label text-right>{{userConfiguration.ECM_ShopCountry.ValueOfString}}</ion-label>
     </button>
</ion-content>
```

**TS File**

```
ionViewCanLeave() {
        if (this.changed == true) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
              title: 'you have made changes',
              message: 'do you want to exit without saving changes??',
              buttons: [{
                text: 'Yes',
                handler: () => {
                  this.save();
                  resolve();
                },
              }, {
                text: 'No',
                handler: () => {

                  this.userConfiguration = this.userConfigurationCopy
                  resolve();
                }

              }]
            });
            confirm.present();
          });
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you do `this.userConfiguration = "" ` ?

Comment: where do you fill this.userConfigurationCopy? u have tried this: this.userConfigurationCopy = Object.assign({}, this.userConfiguration)

Comment: no i can't I must reset the default data

Comment: yea, i used Object.assign to remove the reference of fthe original variable